# Interact with CalDav Server from asp.net MVC

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, caldav, radicale

I am struggling to find any documentation on using a caldav server to store events in an asp.net mvc application.

I have had no problem so far getting a local server up and running using [Radicale](http://radicale.org/). I have also set up iCal events internally using [Ical.Net](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net). Retrieving and updating information stored on the server is the main concern.

I want to write something like:

```
var calDavServer = getServer("localhost:5232");
var calendar = calDavServer.getCalendar();

// Do operations on calendar...

calDavServer.updateCalendar(calendar);
```

Thank you for any help and/or advice.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about ASP.NET and I think that C# support for CalDAV may be a bit weak, but after all CalDAV is just some HTTP+XML+iCalendar. You do not really need a 'library' for that.

[Building a CalDAV client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/) is a great introduction to the protocol.

It looks like you may be able to use [iCal.NET](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net) to handle the iCalendar processing part.